# Excel function that copies rows if they fall within the range of 2 dates

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

So at the top of my Excel sheet I have 2 cells, `A2` and `B2`, where people can enter a starting and ending date.

On a seperate sheet I have an enormous list of starting and ending dates in columns `A` and `B`, and corresponding data for each of these 'events' in columns `D` through `G`. I need my function to copy all rows where the starting date falls between the two specified dates, and copy the data to the first sheet, in cells `A4 - G4` through `A100 - G100`. (I just chose 100 as a large number, to make sure the area where the data gets placed is large enough)

I'm guessing this function I need includes the `INDEX` function, but I only know how to use it to look up one data cell at a time, not how to copy an entire range of cells.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you are not looking for a vba answer then I would recommend looking into a solution that involves the rank function.  For example, use a hidden column that ranks rows whose dates are between cells A2 and B2.  Then in cell A4, do a vlookup or index/match that looks for the rank 1 row.  A5 will look for rank 2 if it exists and so on.

Comment: You can't copy/move data with functions - you need [tag:VBA] to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No helper columns required.

Enter this formula into cell A4:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(data!D$2:D$9999,SMALL(IF((data!$A$2:$A$9999>=$A$2)*(data!$A$2:$A$9999<=$B$2),ROW(data!$D$2:$D$9999),9E+99),ROW(1:1))-1),"")
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now copy the formula to the range B4:D4.

Now copy the A4:D4 to the range A5:D100.

That's it.

Comment: Thank you! That does indeed work. Now how to figure out how it works exactly, so I can possibly modify it in the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say Column C in the data sheet is blank, and free to add a formula.

Let's also assume that the data begins in row 2.

Then the following formula can be put in C2 & copied down:

```
=IF(AND(A2>=Sheet1!$A$2,B2<=Sheet1!$B$2),C1+1,C1)
```

Basically it is saying that if the beginning date of the current record is greater than or equal to the date the user is looking for, and the ending date is likewise within range, iterate the record, otherwise not.

At this point the user sheet can have a simple VlookUp as follows:

In D1: `=VLOOKUP(ROW($A1),Sheet2!$C:$G,COLUMN(B$1),0)`

Copy this across to G and down however many rows you like.